# Angular-gettext extract annotations from .cshtml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor, gettext, po

I'm using [Angular-gettext to extract strings from .html](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/annotate/) and [.js files](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/annotate-js/) for multi-language translation using *Gruntfile.js*:

```
  grunt.initConfig({
    nggettext_extract: {
      pot: {
        files: {
          'po/template.pot': ['**/*.html', '**/*.cshtml', '**/controller.caseload.js']
        }
      },
    }
```

But when I try to pull from a .cshtml file, it is not being extracted.

I need to extract from my Header.cshtml file because I am using it as my Layout for my angular app. The layout basically displays a header bar at the top of every page that contains user information (Profile, Preferences, Logout, etc.).

When I try to add a line like `<div translate>Preferences<div>` to my Header.cshtml file, it doesn't extract into my .pot file. But if I add that same line to my index.html file, it extracts correctly and I am then able to define a translation for it.

Is there a good way to do this with angular-gettext for .cshtml files?

Comment: Please post your solution if you find one. I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this code to your option section.

```
            options: {
                extensions: {
                    htm: 'html',
                    html: 'html',
                    php: 'html',
                    phtml: 'html',
                    tml: 'html',
                    js: 'js',
                    cshtml: 'html'
                }
```

Maybe it's trying to parse your template as a Javascript by default.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I added your options section right before the pot section and everything is being extracted correctly now.